# Are C++ variable templates inline?

Tags: c++, c++17

It has come to my notice that C++ Standard Library defines traits by means of variable templates, which are explicitly declared as inline:

```cpp
      template <class T> inline constexpr bool is_void_v = is_void<T>::value;
      template <class T> inline constexpr bool is_null_pointer_v = is_null_pointer<T>::value;
      template <class T> inline constexpr bool is_integral_v = is_integral<T>::value;
```

I thought that all variable templates are inline by default. Is there any particular reason to declare them inline in this case?

Comment: I distinctly remember reading somewhere that at one point the standard failed to specify the linkage of non-inline template constexpr variables, so the traits were defined with `inline` to be safe. Then the defect was resolved, rendering `inline` unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Class members which are both `static` and `constexpr` are also implicitly `inline`. Non-members do not have this property. And variable templates are not implicitly `inline`.

Indeed, non-`static`, non-member template functions and variables *have* to be explicitly declared `inline`.

Comment: "And variable templates are not implicitly inline": Could you give a reference where it is stated?

Comment: @mentalmushroom: I can't give you a reference to a thing that doesn't exist. Being implicitly inline is a positive property; there's a statement in the spec that says that syntax X is implicitly inline. Not being implicitly inline is a negative property; there's nowhere that says it isn't implicitly inline because *everything* is not implicitly inline, except for the things that are.

Comment: template functions are inline, no? We put template function definitions to header files.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: "*template functions are inline, no?*" No, they're not. *Member* template functions are, but that's because they're member functions. Non-member template functions are not implicitly inline.

Comment: @NicolBolas are free-standing function templates otherwise exempt from ODR? How come we can put them in header files if they are not inline?

Comment: @NicolBolas I see. Put it this way, could you show where it is said that member template functions (and maybe something else) are inline?

Comment: @t.niese *"As soon as you use that function template in two different compilations units with the same template arguments, the linker will complain"* Nope, it's not going to complain. Templates are exempt from ODR even when they're not inline, due to [`[basic.def.odr]/13.4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#13.4).

Answer (score -1):

It is not true that templates are inline by default.  The rules for default inlining suggest that when functions are *defined* within the class *declaration*, they should be considered for inlining.  For templates, since most templates are *defined* inside the template class *declaration*, they are mostly inlined.  However, it is possible to generate out-of-line templates:

```
template<typename T> class templateClass {
    public:
    void doSomething();
};

template<typename T> void templateClass<T>::doSomething() {
    //out of line implementation.
}
```

Comment: Do you think inline would make any difference here? According to C++ docs, the meaning of the keyword inline for functions came to mean "multiple definitions are permitted" rather than "inlining is preferred". In your example both in-class and out-of-class template definitions are already exempt to one definition rule (AFAIK).

Comment: @mentalmushroom I'm not sure, I would love an answer to this and thanks for pointing me towards that other meaning of "inline".  I just know that you can "avoid implicit inlining" by doing out-of-class definitions.

Comment: @mentalmushroom after looking at this more, I believe ```inline``` has two meanings -- one to nudge the compiler to inline code, and another to allow for One-Definition-Rule to be bypassed, granted that the definitions are the same and have the same address.  In my example, I believe compiler may complain about multiple definitions if invoked with same template parameter in different object files...

Comment: The point is that templates are exempt to ODR even without inline.

Comment: @mentalmushroom thank you, you taught me something brand new today.  Just verified that this is completely true, at least with g++